# How to add subtitles on video using ffmeg layer in aws lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, aws-lambda

I tried the below code, but `ffmpeg` doesn't accept files from temporary folder in AWS Lambda.

```
     const {
        spawnSync
    } = require("child_process");
    const {
        readFileSync,
        writeFileSync,
        unlinkSync
    } = require("fs");
    const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var path = require("path");



    const s3 = new AWS.S3();

    module.exports.handler = (event, context) => {

        var string_data = `1
        00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:03,000
        Making the magic happen.`;

        var id = "id" + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);


        fs.writeFile("/tmp/subtitle.srt", string_data, async function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Error Writing File>>>>>>", err);

            } else {

                console.log("Subtitle Created>>>>");
                
               // let fooPath = "/tmp/subtitle.srt"
                
               // var absolutePather = path.resolve(fooPath);
        
               // console.log("Aubsolute Path>>>", absolutePather)
            

                try {

                    var ffmpeg_command = await spawnSync(
                        "/opt/bin/ffmpeg",
                        [
            
                            "-t",
                            "3",
                            "-ss",
                            "00:00:02",
                            "-i",
                            "https://abcdefgh.s3.amazonaws.com/test.mp4",
                            "-vf",
                            "subtitles=/tmp/subtitle.srt",
                            `/tmp/${id}.gif`
            
                        ], {
                            stdio: "inherit"
                        }
                    );
            
                    console.log(ffmpeg_command, "ffmpeg_command");
                    // read gif from disk
                    const gifFile = readFileSync(`/tmp/${id}.gif`);
                    console.log(gifFile, "giffile")
            
                    
        
                    
                } catch (error) 
                {

                    console.log("Error>>>>>", error);
                    
                }

            
        
            }

        });



    };
```

I tried referencing using absolutepath as well, nothing seems to work here. Any idea on what could be the cause?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't accept files"? Are you getting an error message? More information, please.

Comment: I'm getting can't find the file error where as the file exists in `/tmp/subtitle.srt` temporary folder

Comment: What is the _exact_ wording of the error? Are you sure it is referring to the subtitle file and not the input file?